# Ubuntu 12.4 on 3.4.45 kernel: Can't access USB memory stick

Tags: usb, ram, drive

I installed kernel version 3.4.45 [LTS] on ubuntu 12.4 on a Acer laptop. With this configuration, the USB memory drives can't be accessed, some details are follows.

Upon inserting the USB drive `dmesg` shows:

```
[ 1327.354952] usb 2-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 6 using ehci_hcd  
[ 1327.565368] usb 2-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=090c, idProduct=1000  
[ 1327.565378] usb 2-1.3: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3  
[ 1327.565385] usb 2-1.3: Product: USB DISK  
[ 1327.565391] usb 2-1.3: Manufacturer: SMI Corporation  
[ 1327.565395] usb 2-1.3: SerialNumber: AA00000000001947

root@ubuntu:/etc/udev/rules.d# lsusb

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 8087:0024 Intel Corp. Integrated Rate Matching Hub  
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub  
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 04f2:b23d Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd  
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 046d:c52a Logitech, Inc.  
Bus 002 Device 006: ID 090c:1000 Silicon Motion, Inc. - Taiwan (formerly Feiya Technology Corp.) 64MB QDI U2 DISK
```

In the lsusb output above, the "Silicon Motion, Inc." line represents the Patriot 32 GB stick in question.

Could I please know what might be missing in this case? To mount the drive, I don't see any reference to sda in the dmesg logs.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

Thank you thefourtheye for the quick response, here it is :

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/udev/rules.d# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes  
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors  
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes  
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes  
Disk identifier: 0x2e49cc03  

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System  
/dev/sda1            2048    31459327    15728640   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE  
/dev/sda2   *    31459328    31664127      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT   
/dev/sda3        31664128   528005119   248170496    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

---

Ubuntu, here is the result of `ehci_hcd` attempt:

```
root@ubuntu:/etc/udev/rules.d# sudo rmmod ehci_hcd
ERROR: Module ehci_hcd does not exist in /proc/modules

root@ubuntu:~# sudo modprobe ehci_hcd
root@ubuntu:~# 

root@ubuntu:~# sudo rmmod ehci_hcd
ERROR: Module ehci_hcd does not exist in /proc/modules
```

Comment: Please post the output of `sudo fdisk -l` as well...

Comment: thefourtheye thankyou. Amended my question with fdisk -l output.

Comment: It's seem like Ubuntu cannot detect the usb partition on the computer. Did it work with an another pc which also run ubuntu on it?

Comment: Yes, on a dell laptop with same Ubuntu 12.4 with 3.5.0.25-generic, it worked fine. The same USB memory devices could be read without any issues. It appears that the kernel down grade is the main difference here.

Comment: You should try to reload the ehci drivers with these command `sudo rmmod ehci_hcd` then `sudo modprobe ehci_hcd` and replug the usb to see if it work

Comment: What's so exiting about 3.4? Why not simply use an officially supported kernel version and avoid the problem?

Comment: Ubuntu, it appears that ehci_hcd doesn't exist. Updated with logs above.

Comment: mikewhatever, the version 3.4.45 is the current latest long term supported one per kernel.org; I had to do this because the kernel source is going to be modified.